# Books Art Not Downloading from iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, data-synchronization, books

My books are no longer downloading the art (book cover) from iCloud on my iPhone. They show up on my Mac. I noticed that the new books look different in the finder as well. Anyone one have any idea how to fix this? Seems to be since I downloaded Catalina.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Are you saying that the book covers were on the iPhone until you upgraded the Mac and then they disappeared?  If so, how long have you been waiting for them to reappear?

Comment: So, before I updated to Catalina i would upload a book to Books on Mac and it would upload to iCloud and I would be able to download it on my iPhone or iPad and the art would show up. So I added 2 new books today and they uploaded to iCloud and when I went to download the to my iPhone and iPad neither of them downloaded the cover. As you can see in the second picture they even look different in the finder than the previous books uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

So, I was facing the same problem and it was super bugging me. I have "kind of a fix": instead of uploading the book through Mac OS, do it on the iPhone.

1. Delete the book from all devices and iCloud.
2. Put the .epub or .pdf file in a folder on iCloud (just like any other file, like on the Documents folder)
3. Click on it on your iPhone.

It will open Books and sync it with the cover! But I had the problem that, if I had Books open at the same time on my Mac, the book would disappear. So I just left Books open on iPhone, did all the books, and then opened on my Mac. It worked fine!!

Where I got it: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/dov3x4/books_wont_upload_book_covers_to_icloud/